# disable hiding searchBar when scrolling

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I am coding to setup search bar (not from storyboard)

here are my codes that related to searchbar:

```
    var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)


func setupNavBar() {
    self.navigationItem.title = "Tools"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
     navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }


func configureSearchController() {
    filteredData = toolsList.allTools
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .purple
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for tools"
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupNavBar()
    tableViewConfigurations()
    configureSearchController()
}



func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isSearching = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}


func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isSearching = false
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

although with this line of code i ask to disable hiding search bar when scrolling, it is still hiding.

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

May i ask you to guide me to how i can disable it?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Apple's docs I found this:

> You must configure the searchController property for this property
>   [hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling] to have any effect. The navigation
>   controller hides and shows only the search bar provided by the search
>   controller in that property.

I'd try adding searchController to navigationItem.

Answer (score 1):

@very_supercharged thanks  i have transferred searchBar from table view to navigationBar
i have changed:

```
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

to

```
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

And now, searchBar does not hide when scrolling.